# "Installation Type" options

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, external-hdd, gparted

I am trying to install ubuntu onto my external drive via liveUSB.I created three parts called root,swap and home by using GParted.Now it time to install Ubuntu .I came to "Installation Type" window.I can see the partitions I have created.I chose my external disk as a "device for boot loader installation" but what makes me confused is that

1. Do I have to creat another partition here ?
2. When I clicked sdc1/ext4 and clicked "change" icon I see that it says " dont use the partition"  is it ok? should I change it?
3. And which part should be highlighted when I clicked "install"?  dev/sdc  or  dev/sdc1 or  dev/sdc2 or  dev/sdc3

thanks

Comment: Sorry. Are you creating a live usb disk? or trying to install ubuntu in a usb disk? They are different sceneries and implies different procedures.

Comment: sorry.I am trying to install Ubuntu onto external hard disk which is 640 GB. I have LiveUSB  Ubuntu already.I ran my laptop from LiveUSB and I clicked the icon saying "install ubuntu" after using GParted

Answer (score 0):

I would run the USB installer again , setup your partitions on the external HDD and from the dropdown that says "select device for bootloader installation" select the external HDD . To answer your first question - no , you don't need to create another partition

Answer (score -1):

here are few links i came across which may help you.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent
http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-941290-start-0.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst these may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.